# Data failed to be returned from firebase [swift]

Tags: swift, firebase

Firebase not returning data for a given record, despite it being present in the db .

I have some data in firebase that looks like this (2 records to be exact), and conforms to this structure

```
{ 
 users : [
   SOmeBig0lDID:{
        credentials:{
              name:"bob"
              number:"+10778727737"
        }
   }
  ..... other users
 ]
}
```

In my app i am iterating over the phone numbers in my contact list and issuing a search for each number to identify which is a user. When i issue the search, i get back a value for one of my records, but not the other.

In terms of implementation, as you can see below, I am waiting for a search to complete before issuing another one , here is my code. Im wondering if it is just a corrupted record, in which case this is also very worrying.

I am also 100% sure that the phone number formatting is correct when the query is submitted to match that stored in firebase.

```
//get a list of correctly formatted phone numbers up here 

func getuser(number:String,count:Int,total:Int){
        print("Looking for :" + number+"|")
        let usersRef = Database.database().reference().child("users")
        let query = usersRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "credentials/number").queryEqual(toValue: number)
        query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

            for child in snapshot.children {
                let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
                var dict = snap.value as! [String: Any]
                let creds = dict["credentials"]!
                print(creds)

            }

            if count < total-1 {
                getuser(number:finalNumbers[count+1], count:count+1, total:finalNumbers.count)
            }
        })
    }

    getuser(number:finalNumbers[0], count:0, total:finalNumbers.count)
```

I am expecting to get back the record for a number that i am querying , but i do not. I have verified that the number i am searching for is the number that is in the realtime database and have gone so far as to change the number in the realtime db to match exactly what i see the client issuing (it was doing this already however for completeness i wanted to ruled out the client doing some odd encoding) and yet still the record is not returned.

Oddly if i set the number of the record i am not getting returned, to the number of the record i am getting returned , i get both back. (both number fields have the same value).

If this is an issue with firebase more generally that others have experienced , please comment, i don't want to be using somethign that just doesn't work consistently.

any thoughts let me know, been stuck on this issue for a while.

Comment: Firebase is very consistent, doesn't use encoding and won't corrupt data - the issue is with the code. It sounds like you've got a list of phone numbers (in an array) and you want to verify each number exists within your Firebase structure, and if it does, print out the credentials (i.e. the users name). Why are you waiting to search before issuing another? Why can't you use a for...loop to simplify the code? How about denormalizing the data and read in all of the phone numbers at once and filter in code - that would be a lot faster since it avoids banging on the database over and over.